# Anyone successful in debugging unit tests for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode, gdb

I found examples on [how to debug your unit test in Cocoa](http://chanson.livejournal.com/120740.html) or the [ADC page here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/tools/unittestingwithxcode3.html).
But I can't get the debugging to work for an iPhone app target. I can get the tests up and running and they are run during the build, but what I need is to *debug* the tests for some of the more complex failures.

Answer (score 7):

You might consider moving your tests to [GHUnit](http://rel.me/2009/02/21/unit-testing-for-mac-os-x-and-iphone-ghunit/), where they run in a normal application target, so debugging is straightforward.

Comment: I just tried it out, and it has made my life a lot simpler now.

Comment: In [Xcode 4, you can set breakpoints in unit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900577/anyone-succesful-in-debugging-unit-tests-for-iphone/6756730#6756730), using [SenTestingKit/OCUnit](http://www.sente.ch/software/ocunit/) (the unit testing framework that comes with Xcode).

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by setting up a separate Executable for the project that uses the otest tool to run the unit tests, after setting a bunch of relevant environment variables for the executable.  I have used this method to successfully debug SenTestKit logic unit tests.

I found the following links helpful:

http://www.grokkingcocoa.com/how_to_debug_iphone_unit_te.html (also contains help to fix common errors encountered setting up the project).

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/12/sample-iphone-application-with-complete.html (covers both logic tests and application tests)

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otest.1.html (Man Page for otest XCode tool)

Answer (score 2):

The NSLog messages show up in Console.app

Should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 4, you can set breakpoints in your unit tests.

1. Create a new project with "include unit tests" checked.
2. Put a breakpoint in the failing unit test.
3. Press Command-U to test.

Answer (score 0):

If you do Build & Go instead of just build, then you can set breakpoints in your unit tests and debug them traditionally.  This is if you are using the google toolbox for iphone unit testing; i don't know how you are doing it and if the process is different.