# Debugging independent unit test bundle for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode, debugging

I created an independent 'LogicTest' bundle as described in Apple's
latest and greatest [instructions for iPhone projects](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html).

I've successfully set up and debugged dependent test bundles on Mac
OS, just fine.  However I have not worked with independent bundles nor
test bundles for iPhone before.  The test bundle builds and executes
tests just fine, but I'd like to be able to step-through debug it
also.  I feel like a custom executable pointing to otest is involved,
but I don't know the right arguments and environments variables to
pass to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

- This is a [repost](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/xcode/2009/7/16/29458) from the xcode-users mailing list, but I got no response there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this, but I haven't tried it yet:

http://www.grokkingcocoa.com/how_to_debug_iphone_unit_te.html

Answer (score 0):

See also ["Anyone succesful in debugging unit tests for iPhone?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900577/anyone-succesful-in-debugging-unit-tests-for-iphone).